# Add Layout Params to view programmatically - Java

Tags: java, android

I am inflating a view in my activty like this

```
View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_view, my_activity_layout);
```

And now I want to center myView in the regular layout

I tried this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myView.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                    myView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

But got this error

```
android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

How could I center this view?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="250dp"
android:id="@+id/discountView" >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Discount:"
    android:id="@+id/discountTitleText"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: change `RelativeLayout` to `FrameLayout` and set gravity to center

Comment: cause you are use RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout. So change relativelayout to framelaout in layout params.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` instead if `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

OR

You have to change `FrameLayout` to `RelativeLayout` in `my_view.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

**What is error here?** To understand it you need to understand how view/viewgroup hierarchy is created for that refer : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

So if you go back to your view actually you have FrameLayout-->RelativeLayout-->Textview
**Solution**
    Instead of use

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                        (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                myView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

use

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                        (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)myView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.addRule(//your code);
                myView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

or alternatively get RelativeLayout from your view

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout = myView.findViewById(R.id.discountView);
//And using RelativeLayout params as you have done
rootLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)
```